# When executing a script via ssh, how can I transfer variables back to the PC issuing the cmd?

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm writing a pretty simple script that will SSH into the machine of my choice, run a script to obtain things like the number of users logged in, CPU averages, etc, and write it to a file on the PC that issued the command.

This is fine, but I can't figure out how to transfer the data I need back to the issuing PC. For instance, I have a variable called numUsers which is assigned the value of the number of users logged into the remote PC at the time. How can I get that data back to my PC?

Thanks

Comment: Try writing the file to the remote Machine, then sftp it back to you

Answer (score 1):

Send it to the stdout and then redirect the output of your remote execution. Something like this

ssh user@host 'command' >> outFile

or, if you really need to hold it in a variable

ssh user@host 'command; echo $variable' >> outFile

Answer (score 0):

You can use fab (www dot fabfile dot org)(and python)to execute tasks on remote machines and also get results/output on local machine. I have found it very easy useful and highly productive.